# Build a huge matrix with vector components in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, matrix

How can I avoid using a double `for` loop in order to build a matrix `pos` like this code does:

```
pos=[0 0];
   for i=1:m;
   for j=1:n;
   pos=[pos; i j];
   end
end
```

`m` and `n` are numbers such as 500 and 900.

I have to find a better solution in order improve computation time.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Not knowing the language (matlab?) I'm going to guess some form of `meshgrid`.

Comment: The answer is likely language dependent. What language are you using?

Comment: @U2EF1 - Yup, I used `meshgrid` in my solution.  Nice spot!

Comment: @Vincenzo - I have written a solution for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much rayryeng for your great answer!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this by [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html).

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:m, 1:n);
pos = [0 0; X(:) Y(:)];
```

How the above code works is the following.  `meshgrid` (in this case) creates a 2D grid of `(X,Y)` co-ordinates.  `X` progresses horizontally while `Y` progresses vertically.  As we can see in your `for` loops, `m` defines the horizontal boundaries while `n` denotes the vertical boundaries.  By calling `meshgrid(1:m, 1:n)`, I am creating a `n x m` grid for both `X` and `Y`, where each row of `X` progresses from 1 to `m`, while each column of `Y` progresses from 1 to `n`.  Therefore, these will both be `n x m` matrices.  Calling the above with `m = 4` and `n = 5` computes:

```
m = 4;
n = 5;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:m, 1:n)

X =

 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4

Y =

 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5
```

This **almost** follows the format you wish.  You'll notice that by looking at the columns individually, this achieves what you want, but you want to stack all of the `X` and `Y` to be in a `(n x m) + 1 x 2` matrix (1 to account for `[0 0]`).  All we have to do now is take every column of `X` and `Y` and stack them on top of each other to create a single column for both.  We can stack all of these together by doing `X(:)` and `Y(:)`.  `X(:)` will take every column of `X` and create a single column that stacks all of the columns together.  The same is done for `Y(:)`.  As such, we first create `pos` by attaching `[0 0]` as the first row, and we then attach `X(:)` and `Y(:)` as columns to `pos` after, thus completing the construction of `pos`.

Let's do an example as a proof-of-concept.  Suppose that we use the same values like we did before:

```
m = 4;
n = 5;
```

Using your `for` loop, we get:

```
pos =

 0     0
 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 1     5
 2     1
 2     2
 2     3
 2     4
 2     5
 3     1
 3     2
 3     3
 3     4
 3     5
 4     1
 4     2
 4     3
 4     4
 4     5
```

Using the code I have written, we also get:

```
pos =

 0     0
 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 1     5
 2     1
 2     2
 2     3
 2     4
 2     5
 3     1
 3     2
 3     3
 3     4
 3     5
 4     1
 4     2
 4     3
 4     4
 4     5
```

## Minor Note

As you stated that `m` and `n` are going to be relatively large, I would recommend you clear `X` and `Y` from your workspace before you proceed.  `X` and `Y` were only created to help you create `pos`.  As you don't need them anymore, after you calculate `pos`, do:

```
clear X; 
clear Y;
```